# Improving performance of addition with very big numbers

Tags: java, performance, biginteger

I wrote this program to calculate very big numbers without using any BigInteger method. I finished it and it's working properly. I used StringBuilder and lots of parseInt call to get it done. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

*By the way, this is just worksheet, ignore bad programming style, after finishing my job, I will reorganize that.*

```
private String add (String x, String y)
{
    String g = "";
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    int sum;
    double atHand = 0;
    int dif = (int)(Math.abs(x.length()-y.length())); 

    if(x.length() >= y.length())   //adding zero for equalise number of digits.
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<dif; i++)
            g += "0";
        y = g+y;    
    }
    else 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<dif; i++)
            g += "0";
        x = g + x;
    }

    for (int i = y.length()-1; i >=0 ; i--)
    {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(x.substring(i, i+1)) +Integer.parseInt(y.substring(i,i+1)) + (int)atHand; 

        if(sum<10) 
        {
            str.insert(0, Integer.toString(sum)); 
            atHand = 0;  
        }else
        {
            if(i==0)
                str.insert(0, Integer.toString(sum)); 
            else
            {
                atHand = sum *0.1;
                sum = sum %10;  
                str.insert(0, Integer.toString(sum));
            }
        }
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: To "parse" a digit, try `x.charAt(index) - '0'` and `(char)('0' + num)` to convert a digit to ASCII.

Comment: another good idea, thanks. But, what is num? Did you mean sum? I did not understand second code.

Comment: `num` is the digit you want to convert, e.g. sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing it character by character, you should take `k` chars at a time, such that it can fit into a Java `int` or `long`. use some predetermined threshold that can hold both the "block", and depending on implementation, any overflow (i.e. such that `(threshold * 2) < positive_type_limit`). To make things easier, use a threshold that is a power of ten, so you can directly map it to characters in a string-representation of a base 10 number (e.g. if your overflow threshold is one million, then you can take 6 characters at a time) - this also have the added benefit that you can efficiently convert it back to a string.

Then your "blocks" are much bigger. you would then add and do overflow using these blocks and your limit/threshold (which is based on what integer primitive type you use). So basically you are operating on an array of `ints`.

You will still have time complexity of `O(n)`, but it will be a smaller `n` (more specifically, it will be `O(n/k)` where `k` is the number of decimal digits one block represents.)

I believe that all solutions involve splitting the big number into smaller blocks and operating on them. You have already done this, just your current solution is the special case of `blocksize=k=1`.

To get the most of the block, you might use a power of 2 as the limit e.g. for a 32 bit unsigned integer type, you would set your threshold to `2^31` (or you could set it to 2^32, but it depends on where and how you are storing the overflow to pass over to the next element).

I would not be surprised if BigInteger uses a similar technique.